# Saving a backup copy of a word document using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a tkinter GUI that allows to analyse a selected Word document.
The user can select a file to analyse by pressing the upload button.

Before starting the analysis, I would like to backup the selected document.
To accomplish this I tried implementing a function (executed by pressing the upload button as well) which uses the asksaveasfile feature of tkinter.
This somewhat works as it pops ups as save as file dialogue after the user has selected a file using a diaogue box generated using askopenfile.

However, I have not been able to pass the the name of the selected file to this function (file_save_as()) so I can backup that file. I would like to know how I can save a copy of the selected document under a new file name (by adding '_backup' to the original name), without having to manually type this. For example if the selected document is titled, 'myfile.docx', then the backup should be called, 'myfile_backup.docx'. This file renaming should be done automatically

Any form of help would be appreciated. If there are any questions regarding the code, please ask.

The code for the upload button is shown here:

```
    # upload button settings
    upload_btn = tk.Button(root, command=lambda: [file_open(), file_save_as()])
    upload_btn.configure(background="blue", font="{Arial} 16", text="Upload")
    upload_btn.place(anchor="nw", relheight="0.10", relwidth="0.15", relx="0.10", rely="0.10", x="0", y="0")
```

The code for the function to open a file is shown here (FYI, the returned variable 'filename' contains the file path of the selected document):

```
# function to open a Word document using file explorer
def file_open():
    upload_btn.configure(text="waiting...")
    file = askopenfile(parent=root, mode='r', title="Choose a file", filetypes=[(".docx file", "*.docx")])
    upload_btn.configure(text="Upload")
    global filename
    filename = file.name
    file_label.configure(text="Chosen File: " + filename)
    return filename
```

The code for the function to backup the file is shown here:

```
def file_save_as():
    copy_file = asksaveasfile(parent=root, mode='r', title="Backup chosen file", filetypes=[("Word file", "*.docx")])
```

Comment: If you just want to save a backup copy of the original file *in the same directory*, you don't need to use `asksaveasfile()` at all.  Use something like `shutil.copy2()` to copy the file.

Comment: @acw1668 yes, that is what I use in the function file_save_as()

Comment: @acw1668 I would like to save a backup copy of the original file in any directory.

Comment: Then you better use `askdirectory()` instead as the filename for the copy can be constructed programmatically based on your requirement.  Also suggest to use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()` if you just want the source filename.

Comment: @acw1668 so I've used this function to choose a directory: 

`def file_save_as():
    copy_file = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Backup")`. 

But how can I programmatically construct a filename for the copy based on my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the copy of the original file to selected folder, it is better to use `askdirectory()` instead of `asksaveasfile()`, then construct the output filename programmatically and use `shutil.copy2()` to backup the original file:

```py
...
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import pathlib
import shutil
...

def file_save_as():
    folder = askdirectory(title="Choose backup folder")
    if folder:
        # filename is the selected file in file_open()
        src = pathlib.Path(filename)
        # src.stem is the filename without the directories and file extension parts
        # src.suffix is the file extension, i.e. ".docx"
        dst = pathlib.Path(folder) / f'{src.stem}_backup{src.suffix}'
        # copy the source file to destination file using shutil.copy2()
        shutil.copy2(src, dst)

...
```